# Dart HTTP Server and importing a SSL Certificate

Tags: https, dart, certutil

I have create a Dart HTTP(s) server for deploying files. I can have it run the https with a self signed cert. But how do you import a .crt properly from someone for example GoDaddy properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a long struggle I have finally succeeded in importing a certificate from GoDaddy properly into Darts HttpServer bindSecure.

In order to pull this off, first you must merge your key and the certificate from GoDaddy together.

This can be done using a variation of this: 
`openssl pkcs12 -export -in website_cert.crt -inkey website_key.key -out website.p12 -name Name-Of-Cert -passout pass:SECRET`

After...
`pk12util -i website.p12 -d 'sql:./' -W SECRET`

You should now see the cert with the Name-Of-Cert value, (If you have a password on the db, apply the appropriate flags)
`certutil -L -d 'sql:./'`

Now, verify
`certutil -V -u V -d 'sql:./' -n "Name-Of-Cert"`

Credit to: https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2010/06/04/on-setting-up-mod_nss/

Comment: I made a complete tutorial here: https://gist.github.com/stevenroose/e6abde14258971eae982